# Downloading to CSV on an ajaxified page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have an asp/vb.net web app, and for consistency with the rest of the site, I am using AJAX and my control buttons raise events from an ascx. Client Click on the download button is already being used to handle account permissions.

My download to CSV function uses response.write and once I wrote the AJAX the output stopped, though the code still fires.

Currently I am writing another un-ajaxed, blank aspx to do the response.write It is being opened in a new tab/window via a startup script my control button registers.

There has to be a better strategy.  Any thoughts?

Comment: currently on postback the control button registers a startup script to perform the window.open my download to CSV function is passing a string into response.write which has the .ContentType set to text/csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't quite understand everything you said, but when I've done downloads from AJAX controls in the past, I've had to set the download button as a full postback control. You can do this from the aspx/ascx, or you can do it programmatically like this:

```
        // The export button needs to do a full postback, regardless of whether we're in an
        // AJAX UpdatePanel.
        var updatePanel = GetParentUpdatePanel();
        if (updatePanel != null)
        {
            var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
            if (scriptManager != null)
            {
                scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(exportButton);
            }
        }

...

    [CanBeNull]
    private UpdatePanel GetParentUpdatePanel()
    {
        Control parent = Parent;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent is UpdatePanel)
            {
                return (UpdatePanel) parent;
            }
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This is as close as possible, sadly because the .ascx raises an event handled in the .aspx.vb of any page it is inserted into, access to the specific control inside the ascx doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

it occurs to me that I should share my workaround though it is not a true answer.

I open a new aspx with a simple onclientclick="myfunction"

```
        function myfunction() {
                window.open('downloader.aspx?variable=something', '','width=400,height=200');
        }
```

then the page load feeds the query string into my download function  like

Download(Request.QueryString("variable"))

and Download can now use

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=myFileName) & ".csv")
```

I have then used a string builder to write out a header and my csv like

```
stringBuilder.Append("My Explainitory Header" & vbCrLf)
stringBuilder.Append("column 1 Header, column 2 header" & vbCrLf)
for each record in table
    stringBuilder.append(value1 & "," & value2 & vbCrLf)
next
response.write(StringBuilder.toString)
response.end()
response.clear()
```

The clear being necessary to prevent output to page as well as download. The result depends on browser settings but its either a save/open prompt an auto open to excel or chrome/FF download the file and show you the downloaded file link in the bottom-of-screen downloads bar. Filename is sometimes overwritten by excel if it is auto opened.

Works in FF Chrome and IE 10-7

In my case the popup blocker is an issue because I do some form stuff first and then scriptmanager.registerstartupscript the window.open but that is avoidable.