# How can I download my datatable to csv while using ajax?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `ASPX`. I have a `gridview` bound to a `datatable`. How do I make a csv?

`Response.Write` won't work since I put an ajax manager on the page.

Comment: If you  use `UpdatePanels` just set a `PostBackTrigger` to the button which triggers creating the CSV. Then you can use `Repsonse.Write`. Have a look: http://www.evontech.com/login/topic/1983.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Dupicalte the method here (not the selected answer) will work for you.
[downloading to csv on an ajaxified page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021249/downloading-to-csv-on-an-ajaxified-page/18115252#18115252)